# Subsetting a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I posted a question with my original data but it was too much, so I am going to try a simpler method.

I have a matrix, [80,190]. One of my rows is Wins/Losses. I want to subset my matrix into two matrices, one with just the wins, one with just the losses.

My data looks something like this

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c("W", "L", "W", "W", "L")
c <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
newmat <- rbind(a, b, c)
```

I tried using subset

```
subset(newmat, newmat[2, ] == "W")
```

Which returns this error,

> Error in `x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop]` : (subscript) logical subscript too long

Comment: this seems like it is better suited to be stored as a `data.frame` -- you'll notice that as soon as you use `rbind`, the `numeric` rows (`a` and `c`) are converted to `character`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
winMatrix <- newmat[, which(newmat['b', ] == 'W')]
lossMatrix <- newmat[, which(newmat['b', ] == 'L')]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. The which() command is good to know.

Comment: If you like the solution and think it is right, up vote and accept the answer.

Comment: If `"W"` and `"L"` are the only values, more efficient would be `idx <- which(newmat['b',] == 'W'); newmat[,idx]; newmat[,-idx]`.

Comment: @user3949008 - you've got this all very oddly arranged. In R, it is typical to store data in columns, not rows, and to store different types of data (strings, numbers), in `data.frame`s. And `split` would then be the ideal solution - what if instead of `"W"` and `"L"` you had 30 different types? `split` sorts this out very quickly, whereas you'd need 30 lines otherwise.

Comment: @thelatemail: Understand. I am going with the original data format in the question and giving two matrices (win and loss). I would use data frames myself, and not even really split into multiple data frames, but use on-the-fly subsetting to compute what I need per category.

Comment: Apologies, I mistook you for OP - I should have used @mnwepple for the above comment.

Comment: @thelatemail I agree, which was part of my problem. I scraped this data using Rvest from a website and the way I got it was in this form, which became a problem when trying to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 newmat <- t(newmat)
 lapply(split(data.frame(newmat), newmat[,"b"]), t)
$L
  2   5  
a "2" "5"
b "L" "L"
c "3" "6"

$W
  1   3   4  
a "1" "3" "4"
b "W" "W" "W"
c "2" "4" "5"
```